# How can I check if std::io::Cursor has unconsumed data?

Tags: stream, rust

I am writing a low-level network app that deals with TCP sockets where I often need to process binary data streams. When some data is available, I read it into `u8` array, then wrap into `std::io::Cursor<&[u8]>` and then pass it to handlers. In a handler, I often need to know if there is some more data in the `Cursor` or not.

Imagine that the `handle` function receives data and then processes it in chunks using the `handle_chunk` function. For simplicity, assume that chunk size is fixed at 10 bytes; if the data size is not divisible by 10, it's an error. This simple logic can be implemented in the following way:

```
fn handle(mut data: Cursor<&[u8]>) {
    while !data.empty() {
        if let Err(err) = handle_chunk(&mut data) {
            eprintln!("Error while handling data: {}", err);
        }
    }
}

fn handle_chunk(data: &mut Cursor<&[u8]>) -> Result<(), String> {
    // Returns Err("unexpected EOF".to_string()) if chunk is incomplete
    // ...
}
```

However, `Cursor` does not have an `empty()` method or any other method capable of telling if there is more data to process. The working solution that I could come up with is:

```
fn handle(data: Cursor<&[u8]>) {
    let data = data.into_inner();
    let len = data.len();
    let mut data = Cursor::new(data);

    while (data.position() as usize) < len - 1 {
        if let Err(err) = handle_chunk(&mut data) {
            eprintln!("Error while handling data: {}", err);
        }
    }
}
```

This looks hacky and inelegant though. Is there a better solution? Maybe there is a different tool in the Rust standard library that fits here better than `Cursor`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code can be simplified by using [`Cursor::get_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Cursor.html#method.get_ref) to avoid breaking up the input and putting it back together:

```
fn handle(mut data: Cursor<&[u8]>) {
    let len = data.get_ref().len();

    while (data.position() as usize) < len - 1 {
        if let Err(err) = handle_chunk(&mut data) {
            eprintln!("Error while handling data: {}", err);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you haven't shown any code that requires a `Cursor`. Many times, people think it's needed to convert a `&[u8]` to something that implements `Read`, but it's not. `Read` is implemented for `&'a [u8]`:

```
use std::io::Read;

fn handle(mut data: &[u8]) {
    while !data.is_empty() {
        if let Err(err) = handle_chunk(&mut data) {
            eprintln!("Error while handling data: {}", err);
        }
    }
}

fn handle_chunk<R: Read>(mut data: R) -> Result<(), String> {
    let mut b = [0; 10];
    data.read_exact(&mut b).unwrap();
    println!("Chunk: {:?}", b);
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let d: Vec<u8> = (0..20).collect();
    handle(&d)
}
```

By having `mut data: &[u8]` and using `&mut data`, the code will update the slice variable in place to advance it forward. We can't easily go backward though.

> an `empty()` method

Rust style indicates that an `empty` method would be a *verb* — this would remove data (if it were possible). The method you want should be called `is_empty`, as seen on slices.